# Java, copy from a file to another, line by line with an interval

Tags: java, file, copy, buffer, line

I have a file with 120 lines and I want to move them one by one to another file with an interval for example of 1 seconds and to be able to find after 10 seconds 10 lines in the new file.

But for my case, I execute the program with 0 lines in the new files until the end, and then I find the data.

```
String sourceFileName = "D:\\oldfile.txt";
String destinationFileName = "D:\\newfile.txt";

if(evt.getSource() == btnProcess)
{
    BufferedReader br = null;
    PrintWriter pw = null; 
    try {
         br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(sourceFileName));
         pw =  new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(destinationFileName));
         String line;
         while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                pw.println(line);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
         }
         br.close();
         pw.close();
    }catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Second, for 4 files to process in the same moment with different interval, I need to use Threads ? 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I didn't get the second part of your question *But for my case, I process for 120 lines with 0 lines in the new files until the end and then I find the data what I'm not looking for.*

Comment: Sorry, I didn't express correctly what I want. With this code I have to wait 120 seconds to see a data in the file, and what I want is to find after 40 seconds, 40 lines in the new file.

Comment: For the second part, you can do it in one thread as well, but this will be messy. For a clean solution you should use one thread to process one file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are writing to a text file, `PrintWriter` does not write it to disk immediately. Instead, it keeps the data in a buffer in memory.

You could manually flush the buffer to when you need data to be on disk. Just after `println()` call `flush()` as below.

```
     while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            pw.println(line);
            pw.flush();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
     }
```

Comment: I just tried, It's working. Thanks!
If I want to process 4 files in the same time I need to use Threads ? right ?

Comment: @RahXenLegacy. `Thread` make sense when you want to process multiple stuffs parallel.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a

```
pw.flush();
```

directly after

```
pw.println(line);
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: @RahXenLegacy you know you can still upvote (not accept) more than one answer< ;-)

Comment: Yeah I did it and I have a pop up about having less than 15 pts of reputation.

Answer (score 0):

As for your second part, you could do something like this, if you do not want to use threads:

```
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
    FileCopyDto[] files = new FileCopyDto[] {
            new FileCopyDto("D:\\oldfile.txt", "D:\\newfile.txt", 5),
            new FileCopyDto("D:\\oldfile2.txt", "D:\\newfile2.txt", 1)
    };

    try {
        boolean dataAvailable = true;
        int secondCount = 0;
        while (dataAvailable) {
            dataAvailable = false;
            for (FileCopyDto d : files) {
                d.write(secondCount);
                dataAvailable = dataAvailable || d.isDataAvailable();
            }
            secondCount++;
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        for (FileCopyDto d : files) {
            d.close();
        }

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

static class FileCopyDto {
    String sourceFileName;
    String destinationFileName;
    int timeInSeconds;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    PrintWriter pw = null;
    String nextLine;

    public FileCopyDto(final String sourceFileName,
            final String destinationFileName,
            final int timeInSeconds) {
        this.sourceFileName = sourceFileName;
        this.destinationFileName = destinationFileName;
        this.timeInSeconds = timeInSeconds;
    }

    public void open() throws IOException {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(sourceFileName));
        pw =  new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(destinationFileName));
    }

    public boolean isDataAvailable() throws IOException {
        if (br == null) {
            open();
        }
        return (nextLine == null) || ((nextLine = br.readLine()) != null);
    }

    public void write(final int secondCount) {
        if (nextLine != null && secondCount % timeInSeconds == 0) {
            pw.println(nextLine);
            pw.flush();
            nextLine = null;
        }
    }

    public void close() throws IOException {
        br.close();
        pw.close();
        br = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the code with output to the console to follow the process but It seems that there is no access to the method write